# Pageadapter first and second always same

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm building an android application which have 10 tabs ( categories ).

I use a function `loaddata(category_id)` to retrieve array with product list for every category.

The problem is when I load the app the first and second category always have the products list for second one , because  Cardviewholder  is executed only when `loaddata(category_id_1)` and `loaddata(category_id_2)` finished , so the result is the array for the second category_id_2 for both page, first and second one .

here is the execution process :

1. OnCreateView
2. initpager
3. loddata(category_id_1) -- doinbackground -- return array with    category_1 products
4. loddata(category_id_2) -- doinbackground -- return array_with    category_2 products
5. Pageadapter
6. CarviewHolder array_category_2
7. CarviewHolder array_category_2

   ```
   // use a linear layout manager
   recList.setLayoutManager(llm);

   String[] catid = {""+CatId};        
   loadData(catid);

   while (iList.size() == 0) {
       // System.out.println("iList.size() is 0 not yet "+iList.size() );
   }

   Log.w("pageadapter new CardAdapter", " pageadapter new CardAdapter");
   // create an Object for Adapter
   CardAdapter ca = new CardAdapter(CatId);

   // set the adapter object to the Recyclerview
   recList.setAdapter(ca);
   ```

Comment: Just as a side note, instead of doing `""+CatId` to implicitly convert to a String, it may be better and more readable to use `String.valueOf(CatId)`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the same List object (you call it `iList` i guess), because the returned list by `loddata(category_id_2);` will replace the old one (returned by  `loddata(category_id_1);` ).

For exp, you can use `iList1` to load category1 objects, and `iList2` for category2.

Comment: any other solution ? because i don't want to manage  15 List Array , i have 15 Categorys :(

Comment: My first thought, is to load/manage only 3 lists:  one for current page+ the next page + the previous page. But don't forget to refresh your lists when you switch between pages.